# Broadleaf : Unable to save Custom Entity

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

Hi I Have created a custom entity and how can i save the custom entity to database is there any methods to save the custom entity please help me to solve the issue

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadleaf has tutorials on how to create your own entity [here](https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/tutorials/core-tutorials/creating-a-new-entity). I assume that you are now trying to persist this entity. In this case, you should create a Spring component that has `@Transactional` on it:

```
@Service
public class MyCustomEntityService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "blPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public CustomEntity save(CustomEntity ce) {
        return em.merge(ce);
    }
}
```

You can also add Spring Data to your project, create a custom repository extending from Spring Data's `CrudRepository` and use methods there.

Comment: can i use the existing entities in broadlaef and save those entitites data to database

Comment: Yes, with the same methods.

Comment: thaks i have another issue please see the question here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47405796/broadleaf-extending-product-entity-failed please help me to solve

Comment: i have the error while saving existing entity in to broadleaf. i want to save Field type of object it gives error like bean must be defined please help me to solve this

Comment: I cannot help you without a more detailed description of your _specific_ problem.

Comment: see this question to i have posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47466635/broadleaf-controller-calling-failed contains the information