# Broadleaf: extending product entity failed

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

Hi I Have extended the Broadleaf Product Entity and added a new attribute to that Entity and added the admin presentation annotation to display on the admin side

Here Is My Code to Extend the entity:

```
@AdminPresentationMergeOverrides({@AdminPresentationMergeOverride(name = "ExtendProductImpl.productWarranty", mergeEntries = {@AdminPresentationMergeEntry(propertyType = PropertyType.AdminPresentation.EXCLUDED, booleanOverrideValue=false)})})
public class ExtendProductImpl extends ProductImpl implements ExtendProduct {

@Column(name ="PRODUCT_WARRANTY")
@AdminPresentation(friendlyName = "product warrenty",
tab = TabName.General)

private String productWarranty;

 public String getProductWarranty() {

return productWarranty;

}



public void setProductWarranty(String productWarranty) {

this.productWarranty = productWarranty;

}}
```

Here Is my XML files in Core (ApplicationContextEntity.xml) :

http://i.prntscr.com/u2UjARtwRVmI-PswDzxErw.png

Here is the another XML file (Persistant-core) :

http://i.prntscr.com/9Z8y_SplQNKp7HjCw4XyiA.png

Here is the output Screen shot after applying the changes:

http://i.prntscr.com/Gv-ssCaSTa2QbbS5rLB2vg.png

http://i.prntscr.com/eGWugVJRQ-aQqS_heWHsxw.png

Please help me to solve the issue.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 1 more thing and update the demo products to all be of your extended type. The problem is that if you are still relying on the demo data, Hibernate will still treat them as `ProductImpl` and not as `ExtendProductImpl`.

In your code snippet, you also do not have a `@javax.persistence.Entity` or `@javax.persistence.Table` annotations. Also, there is generally no need to create an interface for your custom domain object, it is optional. So assuming that it is actually this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ext_product")
@AdminPresentationMergeOverrides({@AdminPresentationMergeOverride(name = "ExtendProductImpl.productWarranty", mergeEntries = {@AdminPresentationMergeEntry(propertyType = PropertyType.AdminPresentation.EXCLUDED, booleanOverrideValue=false)})})
```

public class ExtendProductImpl extends ProductImpl implements ExtendProduct {

You should then update the demo data to all be of `ExtendProductImpl` type by inserting data into the subclass:

```
INSERT INTO ext_product (PRODUCT_ID) (SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM BLC_PRODUCT)
```

Finally, you might also want to ensure that whenever you create a product in the admin, it should always be of type `ExtendProductImpl`. To do this, use `@AdminPresentationClass`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ext_product")
@AdminPresentationClass(ceilingDisplayEntity = "com.mycompany.ExtendProductImpl")
@AdminPresentationMergeOverrides({@AdminPresentationMergeOverride(name = "ExtendProductImpl.productWarranty", mergeEntries = {@AdminPresentationMergeEntry(propertyType = PropertyType.AdminPresentation.EXCLUDED, booleanOverrideValue=false)})})
public class ExtendProductImpl extends ProductImpl implements ExtendProduct {
```

Comment: here is my full program screenshot http://i.prntscr.com/EHi1xdnWQMyskdoXbFMw7A.png if possible tell me suggetions to update my code

Comment: here is the sample data i have manually added to database http://i.prntscr.com/Ev8gUyarSCOkJuzfHIY8DQ.png

Comment: after applying the changes in my code as you said it will displaying but adding the new product will gives the following error here is the screen shot of error http://i.prntscr.com/f1FJWwonTxWfcOdzoPbrrQ.png please help me solve

Comment: thaks for the sollution this now working properly and saving to the database you helped me a lot thanks for once again