# Broadleaf : controller calling failed

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

Hi I Have Created a Custom controller in broadleaf i have called the request mappings in custom controller but this gives an error

Here is my code for Custom Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/"+Test12.SECTION_KEY)
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
public class Test12  extends AdminAbstractController{
 protected static final String SECTION_KEY = "test";
 public static String nme1="";
// @Autowired

 FilterExtra td;

 @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) throws Exception {
        // This is expected by the modules/emptyContainer template, this is a custom template that gets included into the body
        model.addAttribute("customView", "views/test");

        // ensure navigation gets set up correctly
        setModelAttributes(model, SECTION_KEY);

        // gets the scaffolding set up to display the template from the customView attribute above
        return "modules/emptyContainer";
    }
    //@RequestMapping(value = "check/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     @RequestMapping(
                value = {"/check/{name}"},
                method = {RequestMethod.GET}
            )
public String check(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,Model model, @PathVariable(value="name") String name,BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes ra) throws Exception{

        System.out.println(name);
        String available=td.check1(name);
        if(name.equals(available)) {
            nme1=name;
        model.addAttribute("customView", "views/sucess");
        setModelAttributes(model, SECTION_KEY);
         return "modules/emptyContainer";
        }
        else {
            model.addAttribute("customView", "views/error");
            setModelAttributes(model, SECTION_KEY);
             return "modules/emptyContainer";
        }
        }
/*  @RequestMapping(value = "add/{name1}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String add(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,Model model, @PathVariable(value="name") String name1) {

            System.out.println(name1);
            String available=td.add(nme1,name1);
            if(available.equals("sucess")) {
            model.addAttribute("customView", "views/sucess1");
            setModelAttributes(model, SECTION_KEY);
             return "modules/emptyContainer";
            }
            else {
                model.addAttribute("customView", "views/error");
                setModelAttributes(model, SECTION_KEY);
                 return "modules/emptyContainer";
            }
            }  */
              }
```

Here is my code to save to database:

```
@Service
public class FilterExtra {
 // @Autowired
 @Resource(name="org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.domain.FieldImpl")
FieldImpl f;
 // @Autowired
 @Resource(name="org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.Product")
  Product p;
public static String nme="";
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "blPU")
public EntityManager em;
ProductAttribute pa;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public String check1(String name) {
     Query q=em.createQuery("SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE WHERE NAME=:name");
     q.setParameter("name", name);
     List<ProductAttribute> inf0 = q.getResultList();
     System.out.println(inf0);
      if(inf0!=null)
      {

        f.setFriendlyName(name);
        f.setAbbreviation(name);
        f.setEntityType(p.getFieldEntityType());
        f.setPropertyName("productAttributes("+name+").value");
        em.merge(f);
      }
     if(name.equals(nme))
     {
         return name;
     }
     else {
    return null;
     }
     }

       }
```

Here Is My HTML code:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
      <p> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbspThis is a test</p>
       <form name="filtr" action="test/check/">
             FilterName: <input type="text" name="name" method="get">
             <input type="submit" value="checkfilter">
       </form>
   
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Exception caused at Runtime:

> Sorry, there was an error processing your request. : b2012097-870f-  4e7b-8871-e82844a3cd23

Here is my server log:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'name' must not be null
>       at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.transformedBeanName(BeanFactoryUtils.java:72) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.transformedBeanName(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1117) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:239) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.common.persistence.EntityConfiguration.lookupEntityClass(EntityConfiguration.java:75) ~[broadleaf-common-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.common.service.PersistenceServiceImpl.getManagedClassName(PersistenceServiceImpl.java:268) ~[broadleaf-common-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.common.service.PersistenceServiceImpl.buildManagerCacheKey(PersistenceServiceImpl.java:257) ~[broadleaf-common-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.common.service.PersistenceServiceImpl.identifyTransactionManager(PersistenceServiceImpl.java:182) ~[broadleaf-common-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.server.service.DynamicEntityRemoteService.identifyTransactionManager(DynamicEntityRemoteService.java:346) ~[broadleaf-open-admin-platform-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.server.service.DynamicEntityRemoteService.inspect(DynamicEntityRemoteService.java:95) ~[broadleaf-open-admin-platform-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.server.service.DynamicEntityRemoteService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f7ebcd8b.invoke() ~[broadleaf-open-admin-platform-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.server.service.DynamicEntityRemoteService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4531ea28.inspect() ~[broadleaf-open-admin-platform-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.server.service.AdminEntityServiceImpl.inspect(AdminEntityServiceImpl.java:871) ~[broadleaf-open-admin-platform-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.server.service.AdminEntityServiceImpl.getClassMetadata(AdminEntityServiceImpl.java:103) ~[broadleaf-open-admin-platform-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.web.controller.entity.AdminBasicEntityController.viewEntityForm(AdminBasicEntityController.java:418) ~[broadleaf-open-admin-platform-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.web.filter.BroadleafAdminTypedEntityRequestFilter.doFilterInternalUnlessIgnored(BroadleafAdminTypedEntityRequestFilter.java:84) [broadleaf-open-admin-platform-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.filter.AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.java:58) [broadleaf-common-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.web.compatibility.JSCompatibilityRequestFilter.doFilterInternalUnlessIgnored(JSCompatibilityRequestFilter.java:41) [broadleaf-open-admin-platform-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.filter.AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.java:58) [broadleaf-common-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.web.filter.BroadleafAdminRequestFilter$1.execute(BroadleafAdminRequestFilter.java:107) [broadleaf-open-admin-platform-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.web.filter.BroadleafAdminRequestFilter$1.execute(BroadleafAdminRequestFilter.java:96) [broadleaf-open-admin-platform-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.server.service.persistence.PersistenceThreadManager.operation(PersistenceThreadManager.java:33) [broadleaf-open-admin-platform-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.web.filter.BroadleafAdminRequestFilter.doFilterInternalUnlessIgnored(BroadleafAdminRequestFilter.java:96) [broadleaf-open-admin-platform-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.filter.AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractIgnorableOncePerRequestFilter.java:58) [broadleaf-common-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.common.security.handler.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:107) [broadleaf-common-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.web.filter.AdminSecurityFilter.doFilter(AdminSecurityFilter.java:78) [broadleaf-open-admin-platform-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:157) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:178) [spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.filter.IgnorableOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(IgnorableOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:53) [broadleaf-common-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.filter.SecurityBasedIgnoreFilter.doFilter(SecurityBasedIgnoreFilter.java:77) [broadleaf-common-5.2.0-GA.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]

Please Help me to solve the issue.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this Is Working Fine i forget to call the required url pattern i was called wrong url pattern